# How to loop between 1 and 100, print the numbers alongside their squared value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to:
- create a Python app that will loop between 1 and 100
-the numbers are to be printed out alongside their squared value
-the app should stop when a squared value of 200 or more is reached

-i want to use: user input, if statements and loops

Comment: what is the problem you are having here?

Comment: What did you try already? Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are going to get better results following those tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With user input, if condition and loop :

```
try:
    max_square = int(input("Enter the max square number"))
    for i in range(1,100):
        if i**2 < max_square:
            print("Number: {}, Square of Number: {}".format(i, i**2))
except Exception:
    print("Enter a valid input")
```